# g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, g++, execvp

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I'm trying to "make" a project.

I get this error:

```
g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I have g++ installed.

Comment: I just had the same issue with installing a Python package (pandas) with C++ extension, and this answer [has helped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929308) me. I had gcc 4.9 and g++ 4.8. Once I downgraded gcc to 4.8 with `aptitude` to make the versions match the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 31):

I tried the command @MonoThreaded gave but it failed. I tried below and it works.

`sudo apt-get install g++`

Please don't include any version after the `g++`.

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same issue after upgrading gcc to 4.8
`sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8` (mind the package name)
Then I manually changed the g++ link to a renamed copy of gcc-4.8
My fix was a proper g++ installation
**`sudo apt-get install g++-4.8`** 
For clarity you should use **`g++-4.8`** instead of `gcc-4.8`

Answer (score 12):

I have g++ and gcc installed.

```
sudo find / -name "cc1plus"
```

Gave me something like `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/<version>/cc1plus`

So I added it to the $PATH

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/<version>:$PATH"
```

Comment: Same for me on centOS. Corrected path on .bash_profile

Comment: This works! I use aws ec2, "cc1plus" was installed but not in $PATH so sasl install was failed!

Answer (score 5):

you say you already have g++ installed however it was not installed correctly ... revert what you did to install g++ then run this to install the bundle of developer tools

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf build-essential pkg-config automake tcsh
```

which includes `g++` and the entire `make` toolchain of utils

Answer (score 2):

> I have g++ installed.

You do, but you *don't* have it installed *correctly*.

First run `which g++` -- it's likely that your `PATH` is pointing at something other than `/usr/bin/g++`, and *that* version is not properly installed.

Comment: I have this problem too—and `which g++` gives me `/usr/bin/g++`.