# Where to specify system level dependencies if not in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, linux, deployment, repository

I created a requirements.txt, committed it and pushed it to the repository and then pulled it to a Ubuntu server on AWS, created a virtualenv in the folder and ran it with `pip install -r requirements.txt` It failed several times half way through, with some errors around gcc and g++. After then running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential`, `pip install -r requirements.txt` ran to completion without errors.

It feels like the repository is incomplete.. Where should these requirements go if not into `requirements.txt`?

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do with your requirements file, but rather the fact that you've deployed a new instance. I think anytime you bring up a new instance you'll probably need to do some bit of updating. You might want to consider using docker.

Comment: You need to put `some errors around gcc and g++` that you had got.

Comment: Ok thanks. "Put some errors" where?

Comment: In your question

Comment: The initial errors were `unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`  Then I ran `sudo apt-get install gcc` then the error changed to `gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` after which I ran the commands in the question above then all the errors went away. I just wonder where these system level requirements are supposed to be specified in a Python repository..

Comment: system level requirements are not supposed to go in requirements.txt. If you search your errors, you will find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414109/g-error-trying-to-exec-cc1plus-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: ok thanks. problems are solved. Maybe system level requirements are not supposed to go anywhere